# application.css has already been required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

Dont know what happened. i have deployed code to my server 3 times today and now i get this error.

```
  * ←[33mexecuting "cd -- /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140404020322 && bund
le exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp --
 /home/deployer/loadmax/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/deployer/loadmax/releas
es/20140404020322/assets_manifest.yml"←[0m
    servers: ["108.235.52.160"]
    [108.235.52.160] executing command
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140404020322/app/a
ssets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160]
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 51582ms←[0m
*** [←[34mdeploy:update_code←[0m] ←[34mrolling back←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "rm -rf /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140404020322; true"
←[0m
    servers: ["108.235.52.160"]
    [108.235.52.160] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 838ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'cd -- /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140404020322 && bundle e
xec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /ho
me/deployer/loadmax/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/2
0140404020322/assets_manifest.yml'" on 108.235.52.160
```

Here is the line assets_manifest.yml file

```
---
application.css: application-cbe5df2fd54e4a120dc4a78c89b723d3.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Ruby mines added in several files that it thought i was missing

Comment: Which files were you missing?

Comment: It added application.CSS  where it should of been application.CSS.scss  also changed a few of my .idea files.  As well as added a extra folder in the .idea file called Runconfigurations